# decode hex opcodes into asm or run hex in __asm?

Tags: c, visual-c++, assembly

Is there any means in Visual Studio 2010 (or some other tool on Windows) that can take hex opcode instructions e.g.

`EB D2`

and "decode" or otherwise translate these into human-readable asm?

Alternatively, is there a way to run hex instructions directly in an `__asm` block?

Comment: To execute raw hex opcodes, you can use [`_emit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b80826t.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you mentioned Visual Studio, I assume you are looking for internal tools, or maybe you are using MASM.  NASM has its own disassembler but its syntax is not the same as MASM's.

There is an old trick that I know at least used to work years ago.  You can cast a string to a function in C like so:

```
/*
 * Illustration of executing machine code as a C string.  Works on an
 * IA-32 processor.
 */

#include <stdio.h>

int (*f)() = "\xb0\x64\x0f\xb6\xc0\xc3";

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", f());
    return 0;
}
```

Here the function `f` moves the value 100 into the `eax` register and returns it (`C3` is the opcode for return).  Not sure if that works in Visual Studio's dialect of C, and you might have to update it if you are using a 64-bit processor.  It does provide an interesting alternative to the `__asm` block.

**ADDENDUM**

The program still works fine on a MacBook Pro running Mountain Lion:

```
$ cat hundred.c 
#include <stdio.h>

int (*f)() = "\xb0\x64\x0f\xb6\xc0\xc3";

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", f());
    return 0;
}

$ gcc hundred.c && ./a.out 
hundred.c:3: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
100
```

As was pointed out in the comments below, this kind of solution will not work if the string is in a segment for which the O.S. will not permit execution.

Comment: Does the compiler put that into a code segment automatically?  If not, it won't work on systems where Data Execution Prevention is enabled (NX bit in the memory management unit).

Comment: Aren't all opcodes the same for x86?  The syntax may be a little different but I'd think NASM's disassembler would work fine. BTW, I like that example, but you should rewrite it using VirtualAlloc since it currently results in a access violation.

Comment: @annoying_squid +1 for VirtualAlloc.  It is true opcodes are the same but if the O.P. wants to put something into an asm block the NASM vs MASM vs GAS syntax will be relevant.

Answer (score 4):

The debugger disassembly window is pretty good at that.

Visual Studio has one.  WinDbg has one (or `u` for "unassemble" at the command-line).  Other debuggers such as OllyDbg or IDA Pro may fit the bill.

Or you can look for a standalone *disassembler*.

For that matter, you can find interactive online disassemblers.

http://www.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/run_hex says that EB D2 is a jump instruction.

Comment: +1 Thanks for introducing ODA!  I can't believe I never knew about that.